# JavaScript / JSF2 data (rectangle) visualization in a cartesian coordinate system

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, coordinates

I need to be able to visualize a special sort of diagram. In the past I always used Highcharts or Google charts for my data visualizations, but this time I cannot find any suitable chart in the mentioned libraries.

Actually the desired result should look like this:

[image]

So what I have is a cartesian coordinate system (with date axis), which contains several rectangles. Iam really looking forward to any recommendations on this.

Comment: out of curiosity - what is the chart meant to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick with Highcharts, your best is probably going to be the renderer:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer

You could also work this out using area series, but that could get a little messy after a while...

{{edit:

```
example using the area method:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/8Xwuq/

Comment: Gonna use your snippet of the area chart, which works just fine for me. Thanks a lot!